# Recursively search nested object for certain key OR value

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I want to use recursion to search through a nested object for a certain key OR value and then return that key AND value as an object.

However, I think I am getting the understanding of it a bit wrong, as found always returns empty {}.

Is this because it is getting overwritten? I used Googles snippets to walk through the call stack and can see that the correct key and value are being passed to found, but then it seems to get set back to {} and it continues to iterate through the other objects.

```html
const test = [
  {
    "jack's assets": {
      car: "Mercedes",
      house: "6 bed mansion",
      laptop: "PC",
      phone: "Samsung",
      watch: "Cartier",
      trainers: "Adidas",
    },
  },
  {
    "mikes's assets": {
      car: "Audi",
      house: "4 bed detached",
      laptop: "MacBook",
      phone: "iPhone",
      watch: "Rolex",
      trainers: "Nikes",
      "wifes assets": {
        car: "Jeep",
        laptop: "Lenovo",
        phone: "Nokia",
        watch: "Rotary",
        trainers: "Kickers",
      },
    },
  },
];

function dataLayerSearch(data, input) {
  let found = {};

  for (let obj in data) {
    if (typeof data[obj] === "object") {
      dataLayerSearch(data[obj], input);
    } else {
      if (obj === input || data[obj] === input) {
        found[obj] = data[obj];
      }
    }
  }
  return found;
}

dataLayerSearch(test, "Nikes");
```

Comment: do you expect a single property or more, what should happen for more than the same key?

Comment: what about same level values? should the grouped into the same object?

Answer (score 0):

You could return early on find.

BTW, naming a key as `obj` is misleading.

```js
function dataLayerSearch(data, input) {
    const
        result = [],
        object = {};

    let found = false;

    for (const key in data) {
        if (data[key] === input) {
            object[key] = data[key];
            if (!found) {
                found = true;
                result.push(object);
            }
        }
        if (data[key] && typeof data[key] === "object") {
            const temp = dataLayerSearch(data[key], input);
            if (temp) result.unshift(...temp);
        }
    }
    return result.length
        ? result
        : undefined;
}

const test = [{ "jack's assets": { car: "Mercedes", house: "6 bed mansion", laptop: "PC", phone: "Samsung", watch: "Cartier", trainers: "Adidas", foo: "bar" } }, { "mikes's assets": { car: "Audi", house: "4 bed detached", laptop: "MacBook", phone: "iPhone", watch: "Rolex", trainers: "Nikes", "wifes assets": { car: "Jeep", laptop: "Lenovo", phone: "Nokia", watch: "Rotary", trainers: "Kickers", foo: "bar" }, foo: "bar" } }];

console.log(dataLayerSearch(test, "Nikes"));
console.log(dataLayerSearch(test, "bar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting an empty object back because in your example, your match is >1 layer deep, and your recursive call is not setting the return value to anything, so your original found variable isn't ever being set at the top level. Something like the below would find each instance of your search term and insert that key/value as an object into an array and return the array.

```js
const test = [{ "jack's assets": { car: "Mercedes", house: "6 bed mansion", laptop: "PC", phone: "Samsung", watch: "Cartier", trainers: "Adidas" } }, { "mikes's assets": { car: "Audi", house: "4 bed detached", laptop: "MacBook", phone: "iPhone", watch: "Rolex", trainers: "Nikes", "wifes assets": { car: "Jeep", laptop: "Lenovo", phone: "Nokia", watch: "Rotary", trainers: "Kickers" } } }];

function dataLayerSearch(data, input) {
  let found = [];
  let obj = {};

  for (let key in data) {
    if (typeof data[key] === "object") {
      found.push(...dataLayerSearch(data[key], input));
    } else {
      if (key === input || data[key] === input) {
        obj[key] = data[key]
        found.push(obj);
        obj = {}
      }
    }
  }
  return found;
}

console.log(dataLayerSearch(test, "Nikes"));
console.log(dataLayerSearch(test, "laptop"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear to me what you really want for an output format, but here is a version that will return something like this:

```js
// result of dataLayerSearch (test, 'laptop')
[
  {"jack's assets": {laptop: "PC"}},
  {
    "mikes's assets": {
      laptop: "MacBook",
      "wifes assets": {laptop: "Lenovo"}
    }
  }
]
```

or this:

```js
// result of dataLayerSearch (test, 'Nikes')
[ 
  {"mikes's assets": {trainers: "Nikes"}}
]
```

It is based on a number of functions I [use often](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20hydrate), leaving me to implement only this:

```js
const dataLayerSearch = (xs, val) => {
  const res = deepFilter (([p, v]) => v === val || p .at (-1) === val) (xs) 
  return Array .isArray (res) ? res .filter (Boolean) : []
}
```

The code looks like this:

```js
// utility functions
const pathEntries = (obj) =>
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .entries (obj) .flatMap (
        ([k, x]) => pathEntries (x) .map (([p, v]) => [[Array.isArray(obj) ? Number(k) : k, ... p], v])
      ) 
    : [[[], obj]]

const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number.isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const hydrate = (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, [p, v]) => setPath (p) (v) (a), {})
 
const deepFilter = (pred) => (o) =>
  hydrate (pathEntries (o) .filter (pred))


// main function
const dataLayerSearch = (xs, val) => {
  const res = deepFilter (([p, v]) => v === val || p .at (-1) === val) (xs) 
  return Array .isArray (res) ? res .filter (Boolean) : []
}


// sample data
const test = [{"jack's assets": {car: "Mercedes", house: "6 bed mansion", laptop: "PC", phone: "Samsung", watch: "Cartier", trainers: "Adidas", }}, {"mikes's assets": {car: "Audi", house: "4 bed detached", laptop: "MacBook", phone: "iPhone", watch: "Rolex", trainers: "Nikes", "wifes assets": {car: "Jeep", laptop: "Lenovo", phone: "Nokia", watch: "Rotary", trainers: "Kickers"}}}];


// demo
console .log (dataLayerSearch (test, 'laptop'))
console .log (dataLayerSearch (test, 'Nikes'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

It works by first converting your input into a format like this:

```js
[
  [[0, "jack's assets", "car"], "Mercedes"], 
  [[0, "jack's assets", "house"], "6 bed mansion"], 
  [[0, "jack's assets", "laptop"], "PC"], 
  [[0, "jack's assets", "phone"], "Samsung"], 
  [[0, "jack's assets", "watch"], "Cartier"], 
  [[0, "jack's assets", "trainers"], "Adidas"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "car"], "Audi"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "house"], "4 bed detached"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "laptop"], "MacBook"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "phone"], "iPhone"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "watch"], "Rolex"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "trainers"], "Nikes"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "wifes assets", "car"], "Jeep"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "wifes assets", "laptop"], "Lenovo"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "wifes assets", "phone"], "Nokia"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "wifes assets", "watch"], "Rotary"], 
  [[1, "mikes's assets", "wifes assets", "trainers"], "Kickers"]
]
```

which I call *path-entry format*; these records are similar to `Object .entries` results, except that instead of a single key, we have an array of them tracing the entire path through the object to the node.  Then we filter these to find the ones that match your condition -- here that the value or the key [the final entry in the path] matches your target value, but it could be any predicate, as far as `deepFilter` is concerned -- and then combine those back into an array of objects.  Using `filter (Boolean)`, we remove the empty array indices caused by, say, Mike not having any "Nikes" keys or values.  And we return this new array.  The `isArray` check is because if `hydrate` is called with an empty list of path-entries, then it returns an empty object by default.

---

In any case, this might not be at all what you're looking for, but it finds the data you want, and gives you more flexibility.